# Optimized report caching

Tags: performance, caching, reporting-services

I have an SSRS 2008 R2 that I want to enhance performance on.  Is it possible to cache this report for all clients over a given date range so that even if they select one part of this report, it will still run off of the cache vs. datasource?  For example, if I cache 1/1/12-6/1/13 for Regions A-C and then the user runs this report for 1/1/13-6/1/13 for Region A only, will it run off of cache or the datasource?

If I set this report to expire a temporary copy of the report every 15 minutes, does that mean that if the user waits > 15 minutes, that it won't run off of cache?

Answer (score 1):

There are various options for caching reports with parameters. Taken from [the relevant documentation for SSRS 2008 R2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155927%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

> To improve server performance, you can preload the cache. You can preload the cache with a collection of parameterized report instances in two ways:
>
> 1. Create a cache refresh plan. When you create a refresh plan, you can specify a schedule for a single report or specify a shared schedule.
> 2. Create a data-driven subscription that uses the Null Delivery Provider. When you specify the Null Delivery Provider as the method of delivery in the subscription, the report server targets the report server database as the delivery destination and uses a specialized rendering extension called the null rendering extension. In contrast with other delivery extensions, the Null Delivery Provider does not have delivery settings that you can configure through a subscription definition.

For your exact scenario's the best thing you can do to get an exact answer is try it out, using the mentioned documentations (and links therein) to understand and tweak the details.

(The last question you ask confuses me a bit; if a cached report (w/o preloaded cache) expires after 15 minutes then the report will be run the first time after that, and remain cached for another new 15 minutes.)